# Is it possible to make not lazy initialization of static properties of class?

Tags: static, dart, lazy-initialization

A brief example of what I am trying to achieve:

```dart
class Country {
  final int id;
  final String name;

  static List<Country> values = new List<Country>();

  static final Country US = new Country._create(1, 'United States');
  static final Country UK = new Country._create(2, 'United Kingdom');

  Country._create(this.id, this.name) {
    values.add(this);
  }
}
```

I have a Country class with a private named constructor. I want to create a set of static Country constants and a list of all available countries.

And that's the problem:

```dart
void main() {
  print('Countries:');
  for (Country country in Country.values) {
    print(country.name);
  }
}
```

Because of static members' lazy initialization my **values** list is empty. However:

```dart
void main() {

  print('US id is: ${Country.US.id}');

  print('Countries:');
  for (Country country in Country.values) {
    print(country.name);
  }
}
```

US constant is added to the list only when I refer it in code.

What is the easiest way to fill my static country list with countries without adding them one by one?

Answer (score 1):

Just use a list literal instead of adding it in the constructor:

```dart
class Country {
  final int id;
  final String name;

  static List<Country> values = <Country>[US, UK];

  static const Country US = new Country._create(1, 'United States');
  static const Country UK = new Country._create(2, 'United Kingdom');

  Country._create(this.id, this.name);
}
```

This way you also can use `const` to improve efficiency

```dart
class Country {
  final int id;
  final String name;

  static const List<Country> values = const <Country>[US, UK];

  static const Country US = const Country._create(1, 'United States');
  static const Country UK = const Country._create(2, 'United Kingdom');

  const Country._create(this.id, this.name);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I got the point.
All I wanted to do is to "automate" addition of my instances to the list on their creation. If it's impossible, it's absolutely fine for me. Just wanted to be sure that there is no another way to do this.

Comment: Maybe there is some trick I'm not aware of but I guess not. Using a transformer like the one from the initialize package might support such a scenario.